Haskell language Read File
i have txt
have in customer's info  =
[ Customer {customerId = 1, firstName = "Charlotte", lastName = "White", age = 56, email = "Isabella@hotmail.com", balance = 5645.416, riskNote = "Medium"}
    , Customer {customerId = 2, firstName = "Alexander", lastName = "Miller", age = 19, email = "Sarah@example.com", balance = 9595.98, riskNote = "Low"}
    , Customer {customerId = 3, firstName = "John", lastName = "Moore", age = 31, email = "Michael@hotmail.com", balance = 2777.1067, riskNote = "Low"}
    ]

and
my haskell file
import System.IO
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Data.List.Split (splitOn)


data Customer = Customer { customerId :: Int
                         , firstName :: String
                         , lastName :: String
                         , age :: Int
                         , email :: String
                         , balance :: Float
                         , riskNote :: String
                         } deriving (Show)



main :: IO ()
main = do
    handle <- openFile "customer.txt" ReadMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle

    let dosyaIcerigi = lines contents
   
    -- Customer'ları yazdır
    mapM_ print dosyaIcerigi

I can print this text. I can assign it to a variable and print it line by line. However, I cannot create a list of the customer data type. I can do this within Haskell, but I can't when I'm reading from a text file. Can you help me with this?

deriving (Read, Show).

Let your Customer derive from Read as well:
data Customer = Customer
  { customerId :: Int,
    firstName :: String,
    lastName :: String,
    age :: Int,
    email :: String,
    balance :: Float,
    riskNote :: String
  }
  deriving (Read, Show)
then read the content as a list of Customers with read:
main :: IO ()
main = do
  handle <- openFile "customer.txt" ReadMode
  contents <- hGetContents handle
  let dosyaIcerigi = read contents :: [Customer]
  -- Customer'ları yazdır
  mapM_ print dosyaIcerigi
That being said, often you don't serialize and deserialize with show and read: you use a format like JSON or CSV, and then you use libraries to convert from and to the Customers. This also makes it easier to deal with parsing errors.

How can I extract the customers listed in this text and only calculate the average of their ages? Later, I'll be doing more operations with this data. But initially, I need to organize it as if I'm creating a list within Haskell.

main :: IO ()
main = do
handle <- openFile "CustomerData.txt" ReadMode
contents <- hGetContents handle
let dosyaIcerigi = read contents :: [Customer]
yaslar = map age dosyaIcerigi
putStrLn "musteri yaslari:"
print yaslar
I did this and like it happened :D Thank you so much. i will delivered tomorrow my homework :)
